# how to escape characters in comment that's being read in from jinja2 template file?

Tags: escaping, jinja2

I want to read in the comment `I <3 chickens` from a `config.json` file using a jinja2 template file.

My jinja2 template looks like this:

```
{% for comment in comments %}
    <p><b>{{ comment.owner }}</b> {{comment.text }} </p>
{% endfor %}
```

The character `<` is read in from comment.text
How should I escape it here?

These are the error messages I'm getting:

```
:29.48-29.49: error: Bad character "3" after "<". Probable cause:
Unescaped "<". Try escaping it as "&lt;".
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a filter for escape

```
from jinja2 import Environment, select_autoescape

env = Environment()
comments = [{'owner':'cmlzaGk', 'text': 'I <3 chickens'}]
tmpl_data = '''
{% for comment in comments %}
    <p><b>{{ comment.owner|escape }}</b> {{comment.text|escape }} </p>
{% endfor %}
'''

tmpl = env.from_string(tmpl_data)
print(tmpl.render(comments=comments))
```

Have a look at [AutoEscaping](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/api/#autoescaping)

```
from jinja2 import Environment, select_autoescape

env = Environment(autoescape=select_autoescape())
comments = [{'owner':'cmlzaGk', 'text': 'I <3 chickens'}]
tmpl_data = '''
{% for comment in comments %}
    <p><b>{{ comment.owner }}</b> {{comment.text }} </p>
{% endfor %}
'''

tmpl = env.from_string(tmpl_data)
print(tmpl.render(comments=comments))
```

If you are using jinja2 in a framework which does the jinja setup, I would recommend referring the documentation of that framework. eg. Flask sets autoescaping by default, however requires file templates to have specific [extensions](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/).